# Open New Thunderbird Email Using Python

Tags: python, email, python-2.7, thunderbird

I'm trying to open just a new Thunderbird email and attach a file to it for me to fill out the recipient email addresses' instead of hardcoding it.  I'm using Windows 7, Python 2.7 and the latest version of Thunderbird.

I noticed some other questions like this but they all involved writing a Thunderbird plugin which isn't what I want to do.  I know how to do this for Outlook like below and want to do the same thing:

```
    # open new e-mail in Outlook and attach the Map Package
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    email = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    email.Subject = "Map Package Area of Interest"
    email.Attachments.Add(pkgPath)
    email.Display()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thunderbird and other programs from Mozilla don't use `win32com`. Instead, they use `xpcom`. See [http://kb.mozillazine.org/Calling_Thunderbird_from_other_programs.

There is a python module, [PyXPCOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/PyXPCOM), which could help you out with controlling Mozilla from Python, if you really want to.

You can also use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to script Thunderbird and many other programs, too.